# How to add custom grid templates to Umbraco

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, umbraco7

I'm trying to change default template for grid bootstrap 2 or 3 to spectre css or stark css frameworks. Suggest how to do.

What I have tried?

Copied the code from "bootstrap3.cshtml" and try to changes the class names according the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the css files last? Meaning in your Master.cshtml (assuming you didn't change the default layout page name) you can do

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stark.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the grid use your custom renderer, you must include the name of your custom render file where Umbraco renders the grid HTML:

```
@Html.GetGridHtml(Model.Content, "propertyAlias", "yournamehere")
```

Take a look here for more detail: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/grid-layout/render-grid-in-template